# Azure CosmosDB on Linux

Tags: linux, azure, azure-cosmosdb

is there a way I can run a *CosmosDB* emulator on a Linux machine? I need to setup a development environment for *Azure Functions* projects. There is a solution for storage ([Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/azurite)), I wonder I can find the same for *CosmosDB*.

*(Running a virtual machine is not an option for this case)*

Comment: I have not tried it but I believe there’s a docker image for Emulator.

Comment: They have started working on Linux support - see here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030/suggestions/18533509

Comment: This is how I did it https://timwise.co.uk/2020/09/17/cosmosdb-emulator-on-linux/ (it involves a windows VM unfortunately but at least it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: Today you need a Windows VM to run the Emulator on Linux or any non-Windows platform. We publish a docker image which runs in Windows containers and they aren’t supported on Linux. We’re actively looking at the possibility of a port but that work is at an early stage.

Comment: I see, I just hoped I could find a better solution. Do you think wine could be a viable solution?

Comment: Wine is not a viable solution. The Emulator is a 64-bit product that depends on .NET Framework and a wide range of native Win32 executables: System DLLs, utilities, and this Windows driver: http.sys. Although Wine implements some parts of Windows kernel, the latter (http.sys) is perhaps the biggest problem. It is not possible to use native Windows drivers with Wine.